# ADODB RecordsetChangeComplete event handler declaration in VBA6

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

What is the proper declaration for the RecordsetChangeComplete ADODB.Recordset event handler in VBA6?

The Object Browser's version

```vb
Private WithEvents AdoRecordset As ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub AdoRecordset_RecordsetChangeComplete( _
            adReason As EventReasonEnum, _
            pError As Error, _
            adStatus As EventStatusEnum, _
            pRecordset As Recordset)
End Sub
```

causes "procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name".

Comment: Just lose the `AdoRecordset_` part.

Comment: How are you using this?  Like `withevents AdoRecordset as ADODB.Recordset`?

Comment: @nathan-sav: Yes, `Private WithEvents AdoRecordset As ADODB.Recordset`

Comment: `The Object Browser's version` - why would you ever want to copy it from the object browser? VB generates them automatically and correctly when you select the object from the dropdown at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I get when I allow VBA to generate the event.  Notice the ByVal's:

```
Private Sub AdoRecordset_RecordsetChangeComplete(ByVal adReason As ADODB.EventReasonEnum, _
                                                 ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, _
                                                 adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, _
                                                 ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset)

End Sub
```

Comment: That's a different event, but thanks for the reminder! I forgot about this feature

Comment: @PChemGuy Good catch!  I updated my answer.  Take note of the difference between my event and yours:  the addition of ByVal on some of the parameters.